# which iphone data model to choose?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, data-modeling, plist

i need to get some data somewhere to put in a timeline. the data strcture is like this:

```
- Item
  - Name
  - Year
  - ShortInfo (mainly keywords and short texts)
  - LongInfo (much text with videos/audios (urls)
```

a friend of mine told me i should you a plist and get all that stuff in there, but what about a sqlite database? any advice?

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your dataset is fairly small, plists are way easier to handle than a SQLite database. It's just one line of code to read a plist into a familiar data structure like an array or dictionary. SQL has advantages if your dataset is so large that it does not fit comfortably in memory or if you need fast and flexible searching.

Comment: well i think there are 20 entries max., but no big stuff. i think i will choose plists. if that doesn't work fine, well, i change :) thank you!

Comment: You won't have any trouble with 20 records.